# Преобразовать строку в json из get параметра

Tags: python, flask

Мне в функцию приходит get параметр содержащий json строку

```
?json='{"city": "Москва"}'
```

Принимаю так я получаю параметр

```
json_r = request.args.get('json')
```

Дальше я пытаюсь преобразовать это в json таким образом

```
str_get = json.dumps(json_r)
```

Пытаюсь получить элемент

```
str_get["city"]
```

Но оно выдает ошибку

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: Надо не `json.dumps`, а `json.loads`.

Comment: тогда ошибка `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Выведите `print(type(json_r))`. Если это dict, то сразу обращайтесь через `json_r["city"]`. Если это str, то нужно декодировать из строки в питоновский объект с помощью `json.loads`, как написали выше.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке str_get - строка. Внимательно посмотрите переменную json_r. Вот код, где все работает:

```
import json
string = '{"city": "Moscow"}'
d = json.loads(string)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'city': 'Moscow'}
```

Проверьте содержимое всех переменных с помощью print и вы найдете ошибку